# How to decrypt Buffer in Javscript?

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8, decode

I have the second response from API:

```
{"tx":{"type":"Buffer","data":[1,0,9,20,232,158,30,253,102,91,224,142,24,139,235,24,185,117,167,176,38,148,28,20,41,129,248,114,201,238,177,208,222,27,35,1,122,171,135,131,21,92,179,31,33,191,174,42,2,12,164,138,35,246,143,242,109,80,12,59,106,57,34,215,17,199,1,135,230,180,78,67,80,196,227,183,153,71,161,147,224,1,250,189,221,139,41,130,99,75,200,26,141,62,229,69,188,117,86,25,170,66,195,204,74,182,154,57,29,72,14,189,92,119,54,233,167,9,75,46,8,106,16,32,106,135,254,194,103,248,152,30,240,162,26,70,104,192,219,239,235,88,51,140,187,133,212,15,196,156,234,168,246,65,249,243,153,56,13,58,204,30,208,187,99,57,193,243,94,156,85,127,35,140,118,74,20,243,30,151,13,224,10,89,206,233,76,218,196,60,76,129,31,12,239,215,12,158,58,228,224,183,152,74,250,18,157,96,7,160,158,224,142,150,46,161,202,218,73,218,230,18,50,147,194,191,195,125,8,175,246,228,16,89,36,102,175,155,72,107,229,118,121,242,246,139,65,205,220,49,224,32,146,119,74,143,99,98,237,19,62,158,239,82,179,208,220,120,209,84,222,210,224,80,33,1,142,92,118,126,166,118,107,97,56,242,190,237,172,67,16,192,147,149,238,25,52,150,60,37,49,160,101,249,163,229,113,65,213,14,191,134,3,251,195,225,237,162,195,98,40,17,32,23,156,63,217,117,178,30,0,127,30,53,252,164,164,106,15,234,229,2,158,117,56,121,144,204,9,69,103,254,61,18,58,226,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,195,27,24,204,62,20,138,10,82,147,129,137,32,237,250,237,171,57,30,73,51,108,11,116,219,102,157,16,71,3,66,75,97,226,45,68,30,53,171,117,103,164,211,180,137,139,159,43,165,209,246,114,17,136,249,146,112,80,238,9,94,215,194,46,126,142,208,156,38,69,214,62,144,209,34,130,243,246,194,167,185,148,193,11,208,19,156,163,98,147,199,110,253,98,212,77,6,221,246,225,215,101,161,147,217,203,225,70,206,235,121,172,28,180,133,237,95,91,55,145,58,140,245,133,126,255,0,169,6,167,213,23,25,44,92,81,33,140,201,76,61,74,241,127,88,218,238,8,155,161,253,68,227,219,217,138,0,0,0,0,140,151,37,143,78,36,137,241,187,61,16,41,20,142,13,131,11,90,19,153,218,255,16,132,4,142,123,216,219,233,248,89,0,11,227,225,235,161,122,71,63,137,176,247,232,226,73,64,242,10,235,142,188,167,26,136,253,233,93,75,131,183,26,9,5,33,159,137,154,129,212,255,132,251,89,61,46,223,138,144,172,27,58,179,66,88,247,223,35,62,165,3,2,177,189,46,175,0,27,152,218,127,42,242,189,62,135,161,204,231,199,157,25,245,134,95,207,155,72,154,82,158,139,111,87,41,178,242,3,19,6,0,11,1,7,12,11,17,242,35,198,137,82,225,242,182,255,0,18,122,0,0,0,0,0,19,12,0,11,13,14,1,7,12,2,7,15,11,16,34,102,6,61,18,1,218,235,234,255,255,0,18,122,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,22,0,3,11,4,13,14,1,5,7,12,6,2,7,8,7,15,11,17,18,16,9,10,42,37,74,217,157,79,49,35,6,255,250,0,18,122,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255]}}
```

If I identificate right it's Uint8Array. How can I decode it to string? I tried to use TextDecoder but it doesn't work. There is an open-source software (https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet) that works with this data and it decrypts it perfectly, I tried to find a way how it decodes the string, but no result.

Comment: If you have working *open source* software, why not just look at the source?

Comment: I tried to copy decode function, but by some reason it doesn't work (actually it uses new TextDecoder().decode(message), but if I pass my array to this function I don't get a string)

Comment: What is the source of the byte array? How is the encoding performed?

Comment: It's response of API of marketplace. I don't know how it was encoded, but crypto wallets decode it to text (transaction instructions)

Comment: If it's computer-like transaction instructions then text is just a convenience for humans. There's likely a decoder table for it and, without that table, you won't be able to decode it.